# How to get selected dynamic checkbox in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Here is my code, how to get selected checkbox from this code.

1st..i get file name from sqlite and loop it to dynamic checkbox.

```
private void DisplayData()
{
    fileList = GeneralFunc.GetAllFile();

    var checkBoxes = new CheckBox[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count(); i++)
    {
        var checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

        checkBox.Text = fileList[i].ST_filename;
        checkBox.Id = i;
        checkBox.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        linearLayoutClear.AddView(checkBox);
        Array.Resize(ref checkBoxes, i + 1);
        checkBoxes[i] = checkBox;
    }
}

private class CheckedChangeListener : Java.Lang.Object, CompoundButton.IOnCheckedChangeListener //checkedChangeListener
    {
        private Activity activity;

    public CheckedChangeListener(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked) //check checked checkbox
    {
        string test = buttonView.Id.ToString();
        string checkedName = null;
        List<string> selectedFileList = new List<string>();
        if (isChecked)
        {
            checkedName = buttonView.Text;
            selectedFileList.Add(checkedName); //get selected checkbox put in list
        }
        else
        {
            selectedFileList.Remove(checkedName);
        }


    }
}
```

kindly help me.
my code like this..pls help me.
try to get selected checkbox and put to list.

Comment: Please add your code in the code editor instead of adding the screenshot of your code.

Comment: @emrepun pls help me

Comment: `checkBox.setChecked(true)` ?

Comment: you should really read up on MVVM - looping over controls to map them to data it's not how it should done. You work with your plain data and use bindings to display it in your UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox in Xamarin has a property called Checked. Does not have the same methods to set it to checked or check if it is checked as in Java.

```
// Reverse checked
if (checkbox.Checked)
{
    checkbox.Checked = false;
}
else
{
    checkbox.Checked = true;
}
```

You can also loop through checkboxes:

```
var checkboxList = new List<CheckBox>();
//Create new instance of checkbox
//var checkbox = new CheckBox();

checkboxList.Add(checkbox);

//Loop
foreach (var checkbox in checkboxList)
{
    checkbox.Checked = true;
}
```

**EDIT**

As per the question in the comment:

> how about i use. checkBoxes[i].CheckedChange += CheckedControl;
>
> private void CheckedControl(object sender, EventArgs e) { //do thing here }

You would then check if `sender` is a checkbox:

```
protected void CheckedControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is CheckBox)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            // It is checked
        }
        
        //Change the checked status
        checkbox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

> my code can me like this ?
>
> ```
> public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
> {
>     string test = buttonView.Id.ToString();
>     List<string> selectedFileList = new List<string>();
>     if (isChecked)
>     {
>         string checkedName = buttonView.Text;
>         selectedFileList.Add(checkedName);
>     }
> }
> ```

You can add the `CheckedChange` to `CheckedControl` and call `OnCheckedChanged` from within:

```
protected void CheckedControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is CheckBox)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

        OnCheckedChanged(checkbox);
    }
}
```

Then in your `OnCheckedChanged` you have `List<string> selectedFileList` - I would move that out of the method into the class `private List<string> selectedFileList`

Your method will end up looking like this:

```
public void OnCheckedChanged(CheckBox checkbox)
{
    if (selectedFileList == null)
    {
        selectedFileList = new List<string>();
    }
    
    string test = checkbox.Id.ToString();
    string checkedName = checkbox.Text;
    
    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        selectedFileList.Add(checkedName);
    }
    else
    {
        selectedFileList.Remove(checkedName);
    }
}
```

**WORKING CODE**

---

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private LinearLayout linearLayoutClear;
        //private CheckBox[] checkBoxes;
        private List<string> selectedFileList;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            linearLayoutClear = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutClear);

            DisplayData();

            btnGetAllChecked = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGetAllChecked);
            btnGetAllChecked.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                if(selectedFileList != null)
                {
                    Android.Util.Log.Debug("App.MainActivity", "AllChecked: " + string.Join(", ", selectedFileList));
                }
            };
        }

        private void DisplayData()
        {
            var fileList = GeneralFunc.GetAllFile();

            //checkBoxes = new CheckBox[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count(); i++)
            {
                var checkBox = new CheckBox(this);

                checkBox.Text = fileList[i].ST_filename;
                checkBox.Id = i;
                checkBox.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

                checkBox.CheckedChange += CheckBox_CheckedChange;

                //Array.Resize(ref checkBoxes, i + 1);
                //checkBoxes[i] = checkBox;

                linearLayoutClear.AddView(checkBox);
            }
        }

        private void CheckBox_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is CheckBox)
            {
                var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

                string test = checkbox.Id.ToString();
                string checkedName = checkbox.Text;

                if (selectedFileList == null)
                {
                    selectedFileList = new List<string>();
                }

                if (checkbox.Checked)
                {
                    selectedFileList.Add(checkedName); //get selected checkbox put in list
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedFileList.Remove(checkedName); //checkbox is not checked anymore so remove it from the list
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about i use.
checkBoxes[i].CheckedChange += CheckedControl;

Comment: private void CheckedControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
//do thing here
        }

Comment: my code can me like this ?
public void OnCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, bool isChecked)
            {
                string test = buttonView.Id.ToString();
                List<string> selectedFileList = new List<string>();
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    string checkedName = buttonView.Text;
                    selectedFileList.Add(checkedName);

                }

            }

            }

Comment: selectedFileList.Add(checkedName);  like this end up will only added the last checked checkbox..

Comment: Yes, it will add and remove the checkboxes as you check or uncheck them. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: checkbox..meaning to say user are able to select multiple checkbox..so i put in a list..now only add 1 value to the list..

Comment: Yes, It will, because you are instantiating the `List<string> selectedFileList = new List<string>();` each and everytime a checkbox is checked. Like I said in my answer, Move the List<string> out of that method...

Comment: @GohHan no it won't because `private List<string> selectedFileList;` has not been initialized yet. So I check if it is null (this will only happen once) then I make it not null

Comment: @GohHan Just click on the answer`s Green checkmark on the top left of the answer